# Postman Test Script

Tags: javascript, testing, postman

Is it possible to print out a test result in Postman?  I have a test written in the test scripts and I want to be able to put out the value of the key that fails when I run the test.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["value is " + jsonData.value] = jsonData.value === 100;
```

Also you can print out value from environment, for example:

```
const value = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('value');
tests["value should be " + value] = jsonData.value === 100;
```

If you want you can use ES6 features for test scripts in Postman. So let refactor:

```
tests[`value is ${jsonData.value}`] = jsonData.value === 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use these tests to show alert on **Test Results** tab:

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

or

```
pm.test("Content does not have IP address.", function(){
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.not.include("IP Address");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**+1 for Oguzhan Kircali.** the pm.test / pm.expect is the latest, BDD and cool syntax available in Postman to write tests.

I add a precision to Oguzhan message, this syntax allows to define a message in case of check failure, using this syntax:

```
pm.test("Content does not have IP address.", function(){
    return pm.expect(pm.response.text(), "Content has IP address").to.not.include("IP Address");
});
```

---

**Last detail:**
It is better to send a "RETURN" on the last pm.expect(), or after all the pm.expect(), else you will get some errors if you loop on your checks.
Example:

```
pm.test("Content does not have IP address.", function(){
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.not.include("IP Address");
    return pm.expect(pm.response, "Response status code is not correct").to.have.status(200);
});

//OR

pm.test("Content does not have IP address.", function(){
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.not.include("IP Address");
    pm.expect(pm.response, "Response status code is not correct").to.have.status(200);
    return true;
});
```